# How to extract text and link html in each iteration of td's content

Tags: jquery, html

i am iterating in the content of td and td has text and links. i tried this code to show text and html in alert but was not successful

```
var $list = $('<ul />');
var strData='';
$elements.each(function(){
    if($(this).html()===null)
    {
        strData=strData+$(this).text();
      alert($(this).text());
    }
    else
    {
        strData=strData+$(this).html();
      alert($(this).html());
    }
    var $item = $('<li />').append($(this));      
    $list.append($item);
});
```

full code is here https://jsfiddle.net/tridip/41s1pq3a/26/

please tell me how to show text and html in alert box of each iteration. thanks

Comment: The alert is coming fine, what is wrong?

Comment: this line `$(this).html())` should give me `<a href="/Show2" >2</a>` but getting only 2.

Comment: IF you want to show the element contents, you're going to need to remove this filter: `var $elements = $('.webgrid-footer td').contents().filter(function() {
  return (this.nodeType === 3 && $.trim(this.nodeValue) !== '')
         || this.nodeType === 1;
});  `

Comment: Remove the filter from `$elements`.

Comment: can u give me full revised code.

Comment: Why do you want to **alert** html? THAT is actually the issue.  What are you going to do with it - let's solve the REAL problem, not how to ALERT the html code.

Comment: i want to develop the html in js variable just concatinate in loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in `elements` jQuery object, you have `1` and all `<a ... > .. </a>` and all `<img...>`, and when you are trying to get their `text()` you are just getting the `innerHTML` of that node and you need something like `.outerHTML`. which will solve your problem but you should not use `.outerHTML` directly as its browser compatibility is not good.

You can use this function

```
function getOuterHtml($el){
    var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
    wrapper.appendChild($el[0].cloneNode(true));
    return wrapper.innerHTML;
}
```

pretty much self explanatory.

Now get the text using `getOuterHtml($el)`.

[***Live Fiddle***](https://jsfiddle.net/41s1pq3a/29/)